# using switch statement in php with sql query result

Tags: php, mysql

nice to speech with you again, i have some issue with my query as i will show you below
i have mysql query to select some data according to student name and one of the column result i day and in my data base i used days as number [Sunday=0 , Monday=1,.....]
so i need to convert the result number to string according to its date
This is my query

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT sa.tag_id,s.name ,lt.lecture_name,lt.lecturer_name,lt.dev_tag,lt.start,lt.end,sa.ads_ratio,sa.abs_hours,sa.days FROM students_absence sa INNER JOIN students s ON s.tag_id = sa.tag_id INNER JOIN lecture_table lt ON lt.id = sa.lecture_name WHERE sa.tag_id LIKE '%".$query."%' AND(`name` LIKE '%".$_SESSION['username']."%')")  or die(mysql_error());
```

so i need to convert the result of sa.days [Sunday=0 , Monday=1,.....] to string and display it with other result
any one can advise

Comment: you can use a while loop and switch for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a case statement within SQL:-

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT sa.tag_id, 
                                    s.name , 
                                    lt.lecture_name, 
                                    lt.lecturer_name, 
                                    lt.dev_tag, 
                                    lt.start, 
                                    lt.end, 
                                    sa.ads_ratio, 
                                    sa.abs_hours, 
                                    CASE sa.days
                                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Sunday'
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
                                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
                                        WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
                                        WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
                                        WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
                                        ELSE 'Unknown'
                                    END AS DayName
                            FROM students_absence sa 
                            INNER JOIN students s ON s.tag_id = sa.tag_id 
                            INNER JOIN lecture_table lt ON lt.id = sa.lecture_name 
                            WHERE sa.tag_id LIKE '%".$query."%' AND(`name` LIKE '%".$_SESSION['username']."%')")  or die(mysql_error());
```